# Ubuntu for Windows incorrect path when using symlink

Tags: windows, bash, symbolic-link

I have "Bash on Ubuntu for Windows" installed where everything seems to be working fine except for a symbolic link. I have created a symlink in my home folder to my Documents folder. If I cd via that symlink it will indeed show my folders if I use ls. The problem is whenever I cd into a subfolder and use ls it shows me the content of the previous folder. The path, however, is updated correctly. Funnily enough, when I try to do cd into that same subfolder it will update the path again.

Example:

```
pwd -> /home/MYNAME
cd into symlink Document -> pwd -> /home/MYNAME/Documents
ls -> content of Documents
cd into Downloads -> pwd -> /home/MYNAME/Documents/Downloads
ls -> content of Documents
cd into Downloads again -> pwd -> /home/MYNAME/Documents/Downloads/Downloads
```

I can do this infinitely. Whenever I do these things from the absolute path and not use symlinks it works fine, but that a bit cumbersome. I noticed that the working directory when I use a symlink to go to Documents is different from the working directory when I use the whole /mnt/c/Users... but that seems logical. Any ideas?

Comment: I have the same problem, it seems to be a bug, because in Microsoft documentation says the symlinks should work: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/faq

Comment: Interesting. Well, good to know that I'm not the only one, but this probably also means that reinstalling will be of no use. Please let me know when you have a solution, though.

Comment: I had this problem on Ubuntu 14, but since I upgraded to 16 it seems to be fixed. It is not really a fix, but hopefully will help you as well.

Comment: as @ThunderGT says, it's fixed in Ubuntu 16. You cannot upgrade it directly, you need to install Windows Creator Update to upgrade to Bash on Ubuntu 16